# How to make ASP.NET website and ASP.NET Core website work on a same server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

There is a domain name www.xxx.com. This is a ASP.NET web site, and it is working well. There is a second level domain name which is yyy.xxx.com. This is an ASP.NET Core 2.0 website. This yyy.xxx.com is what I am developing.

I try to publish and upload ASP.NET Core web application to yyy.xxx.com. Then both websites are on same server. I know I have to install some software to make ASP.NET Core web application work on the server.

So my question is can both ASP.NET website and ASP.NET Core website be visited at same time? I am afraid once I install some software which make ASP.NET Core website can work, the ASP.NET website will work well.

I try use ASP.NET Core 2.0 to develop my website again. Before the new website can work perfect I want the current website to work. That is why there are 2 websites on a same server, one is ASP.NET, the other is ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Web servers serve the web applications to users. In Microsoft environment, when one talks about web servers, she, most probably, means Internet Information Services (IIS). So, in your case IIS will handle your web applications. An appropriate IIS version can handle any type of web application. So, ASP.NET or .NET Core does not matter. IIS can handle your applications as long as you can configure your apps appropriately.

Comment: There is not enough information to tell you whether this is going to work or not. I suggest trying this out on a separate server first (maybe your local development machine, with whatever web server you're using).

Comment: Have the ASP.NET service listen on one port and the ASP.NET Core service listen on another port (arbitrary, like 5000 and 6000, since you can't have two services bound to the same port). You then need to tell your server/reverse proxy (IIS or nginx for example) to map http requests from www.xxx.com:80 to yourServerIp:5000 and from yyy.xxx.com:80 to yourOtherServerIp:6000. I believe IIS does this through Application Request Routing but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just install the asp.net core hosting runtime from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download)

Follow [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to understand how to deploy your asp.net site to IIS. Basically, it will be a separate IIS App Pool for .net core site and another one for the asp.net framework site. You can then change the binding to set the host header for each site.

Comment: please read my this answer below  ↓ ↓ ↓, too many characters, i can not post a comment

Comment: hi, i just contact the company which provide virtual host service, they just told publish my asp.net core web application directly, everything must be fine. actually it is true. so i do not have to worry about anything without doing any extra work. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

too many characters in my words so i post this answer instead of post a comment.

what i did is:
1.create a second level domain name, such as xxx.mydomain.com
2.open iis to create a website
3.publish my sample asp.net core web application and uplaod to the website.

which cause my top level domain website www.mydomain.com can not work, there is a 500 error.
the error message probably is can not handle web core ... or something. Until i open iis and 
remove the second level domain, www.mydomain.com can work again.

so i do not dare to do anymore on host directly. dependence on my research, if i should follow 
these steps below to make asp.net and asp.ent core website can work on a same host at same time?
1. install dotnet-hosting-2.1.11-win.exe
2. install aspnetcore-runtime-2.1.11-win-x86.exe
3. open iis to config the second level domain website
4. publish and upload files to the folder of the second level domain website

I wish it is all i should do to reach my goal. but there is something make me do not feel good. 
it says asp.net core host in iis can catch all requests before iis then deliver to asp.net core web application 
so asp.net web appllication does not have any chance to get request. dependence on my first bad experience, it 
looks it is true and that cause my www.domain.com website can not work.

so what i should do ? thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think your issue is related to as.net core. it is mainly domain configuration issue on IIS

Comment: hi, i just contact the company which provide virtual host service, they just told publish my asp.net core web application directly, everything must be fine. actually it is true. so i do not have to worry about anything without doing any extra work. thanks for your answer.